# GoogleSheets, gostaria que toda vez que eu preenchesse uma célula ela ficasse maiúscula

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

**Possuo essa function, porém ela só funciona quando eu executo ela, gostaria que ao dar o input na célula ela já funcionasse sem precisar executar a todo momento.**

function myFunction() {
var ss=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheets");

for (var i=2;i<=1000;i++){

var range = ss.getRange(i,5);
var value = range.getValue();

range.setValue(value.toUpperCase())

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acesse Extensões / Apps Script. Em Arquivos, clique no "+" e depois cole o código abaixo:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

O qual interpretará todas as edições e converterá para maiúscula. Veja se assim te atende.

Comment: Não preciso apontar a sheet nem a coluna?

Comment: Ocorreu um erro ao executar o cógio: Erro TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Não é para executar ali. É só colocar o script onde foi indicado, salvar e fazer o teste na planilha

Comment: Exemplo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FTI3r34u7aGPNwUc17b0AngXZGNydpgeJFWaXvmWD4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Aí na planilha, só vc digitar e teclar enter ou tab e a mágica acontece

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, funcionou só estava com um delay, você é o cara!
Obrigado!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!